# Firefox Addon (SDK) - Attach a script to a tab when URL changes, before page has loaded

Tags: tabs, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am working on a Firefox Extension, using the SDK. The addon will be changing the CSS on specific websites (by attaching a stylesheets in the head). They obviously need to be attached before the main content of the page loads.

I need to be able to listen for the URL of a tab changing, and attach a script, **before** the tab content has loaded. The script will wait until the `<head>` has loaded before attaching the stylesheets.

I tried using `tabs.on('ready', function(tab) { tab.attach(...) } )`, but this does not work, because it listens for the tab to be fully loaded, and then runs the code inside the `function()`

I also tried `pageMod`, but this does the same as the above. It attaches to the pages I need it to, but only after they are fully loaded.

Does anyone know how to detect for a tab URL change, before the page is ready?

**Note:** Please **do not** answer with a `setInterval()` method, I cannot state this enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out how to do it, I had not read the `pageMod` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) well enough.

You can specify when the script is attached, using `contentScriptWhen: "when"`, where `when` can be `start`, `ready` or `end` (obviously I used `start`)